# MDX / Analysis Services Calculating Month To Date

Tags: mdx, ssas

I don't usually get involved with MDX if I dont have to, but....

I have a cube with simple fact table linked to a time dimension (with date,month,year columns and so on) and I want to be able for a given day of the month calculate the month to date total for that day.

In SQL it would be a doddle, however I'm not sure of how to achieve this in MDX.

**Update I have an example working for a fixed date. Now I want to know how to do this for any possible date**

```
WITH
MEMBER MTD_15_Feb_2010 AS
Aggregate
(
  MTD([Date].[Year Name -  Quarter Name -  Month Name -  Name].[Name].[02/15/2010]),
  [Measures].[Value]
)
SELECT
{
 MTD_15_Feb_2010
} ON 0
FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: If you can provide more details about your cube and time dimension, I can provide an example MDX in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create the MDX using the `MTD` function. It will return the set of all days from the first of the month up to the member passed to the function.

**Edit:** There are multiple ways to update your example for any day. I would suggest replacing the date member `[02/12/2010]` with the `CURRENTMEMBER` function. This would also allow you to display the value for multiple dates as in the example below.

```
WITH MEMBER [MTD_Value] AS AGGREGATE (
      MTD([Date].[Year Name -  Quarter Name -  Month Name -  Name].[Name].CURRENTMEMBER)
      , [Measures].[Value]
    )
SELECT [MTD_Value] ON 0
  , {
      [Date].[Year Name -  Quarter Name -  Month Name -  Name].[Name].[02/15/2010]
      , [Date].[Year Name -  Quarter Name -  Month Name -  Name].[Name].[01/15/2010]
      , [Date].[Year Name -  Quarter Name -  Month Name -  Name].[Name].[02/15/2009]
    } ON 1
FROM [Cube]
```